# How to fetch value from resource file inside JavaScript in ASP.net MVC view using Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

Currently I am using this hard code to store a message.

```
$('#erroremptype').html = "Please select employee type";
```

Now I need to change it. I have created a resource file and store key value.

**How can I get the value from the resource file and replace it with** `$('#erroremptype').html`

In my .resx file I have 
**Name:** Error Message
**Value:** Please select employee type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#erroremptype').html = '@Resources.ErrorMessage';
```

Comment: Are you getting any error, when you write my suggestion?

Comment: Resource file is not getting reffered!

Comment: maybe you need the namespace something like : `@YourApp.Resources.ErrorMessage`